# Combinatorics choosing members for a class.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

The question goes as follows:

> We have two classes of students, Class A and Class B and $n$ students to sort into either class. We randomly choose a number $x$ between $1$ and $n-1$ to give us the class size. $x$ is then the size of Class A. From this we pick the students for the class A with each set of students chosen being equally likely. Then the remaining students ($n-x$) make up Class B. Consider a particular student, student $1$. What is the probability of the class containing student $1$ to have a size $m$ for $m$ from $(1.\;.\;.\;n-1)$

This is my working so far. I believe we need to use Baye's conditional formula to work out the probability of the size of the class given that student $1$ is in said class. Hence $$P(\text{size of class}|\text{Student}\; 1 )=\frac{P(\text{Student}\; 1|\text{size of class})\cdot P(\text{size of class})}{P(\text{Student}\; 1)}$$ Now $$P(\text{Student}\; 1|\text{size of class})=\frac{n-1\choose m-1}{n\choose m}$$

And $P(\text{size of class})=\frac{1}{n-1}$. However I'm having trouble seeing where $P(\text{Student}\; 1)$ comes from. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: There are $2^{n-1}-1$ possible classes that contain Student $1$. (Why?) For a given $m$, how many of them have $m$ members?

Comment: For any given $m$, the number of possible combinations of the class is $n\choose m$. I'm not sure how to look at this for the class containing student 1. I'm definitely missing something....

Comment: @JJabrams: To form a class of $m$ students that includes Student $1$, you have to pick $m-1$ other students. In how many different ways can you do this?

Comment: Choosing $m-1$ students from $n-1$ right? Is this not using $n-1\choose m-1$? Sorry I'm not grasping this

Comment: @JJabrams: Yes, that’s correct. That’s the number of $m$-person classes that contain Student $1$. There are $2^{n-1}-1$ possible $m$-person classes altogether. Therefore . . . ?

Comment: Ok yeah I understand you divide them. How did you get that there is $2^{n-1}-1$ possible size $m$ classes?

Comment: @JJabrams: Oops: I mistyped that last comment. I meant to write that there are altogether $2^{n-1}-1$ possible classes that contain Student $1$. The reasoning for that is similar to the reasoning that leads you to $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ for the number of $m$-person classes containing Student $1$; can you work it out?

Comment: Ok I think so. Since we are dividing the students into two classes we have that we have $2^{n-1}$ possible classes. Hence we remove the class in which Student $1$ does not belong to giving $2^{n-1}-1$. Though there would be more than one class that doesn't contain Student 1....?

Comment: @JJabrams: You’re making it too hard. To make a class containing Student $1$, you start with Student $1$ and add some subset of the remaining $n-1$ students. There are $2^{n-1}$ such subsets. However, there’s one that you can’t use; what is it, and why?

Comment: Ah of course! you can't use class comprised of every student as there needs to be a student in the other class. Thanks! So the probability of student $1$ being in the class we observe is $\frac{{n-1}\choose {m-1}}{2^{n-1}-1}$

Comment: @JJabrams: There you go! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can clarify things a bit by writing out your events in greater detail. The event "size of class = n" is actually "size of class we observe = n", and the event "Student 1" is actually "Student 1 is in the class we observe". So when you're looking for $P(\text{Student 1})$, what you're looking for is the probability that Student 1 is in the class you're observing, before knowing how large the class is.

There are two ways of thinking about how you calculate this value, and both will take you to the same answer.

#### First Way

The first way to calculate this probability is as the expected value of $P(\text{Student 1})$ for unknown class size. That is, $$P(\text{Student 1}) = \sum P(\text{Student 1} \mid \text{class size}) \cdot P(\text{class size})$$ where the sum is taken over all possible values of class size.

#### Second Way

The second way is to recall that what Bayes' Theorem gives you is a *probability*. Therefore, $P(\text{class size = x} \mid \text{Student 1})$ must sum to $1$ if you sum over all values $x$ of class size. Since the denominator $P(\text{Student 1})$ doesn't depend on class size, we can write \begin{align*}1 = \sum P( \text{class size}\mid \text{Student 1} ) & = \sum \frac{P(\text{Student 1} \mid \text{class size}) \cdot P(\text{class size})}{P(\text{Student 1})} \\
& = \frac{\sum P(\text{Student 1} \mid \text{class size}) \cdot P(\text{class size})}{P(\text{Student 1})}\end{align*} and therefore $$P(\text{Student 1}) = \sum P(\text{Student 1} \mid \text{class size}) \cdot P(\text{class size}).$$

Comment: Thanks! Is my general approach right? I wasn't sure about using Baye's as it doesn't specifically mention conditional probability

Comment: Yes, your general approach to use Bayes' Theorem is correct.